# Formated output

Tags: python, python-requests, formatting

I'm making a request in restapi to show application version, but the output i got is not the expected, i want to format this data.

```
from requests.api import request
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import re
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

bipTmb='https://api1-foo'
bipAws='https://api2-foo'

def requestGet(bipTmb, bipAws):
    cont = []
    for urls in [bipTmb, bipAws]:
        url = urls + '/mgmt/tm/sys?$top=4'
        headers = {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('auth', 'pass'))
        data = response.json()
        data = data['items']
        reference = data[0]
        version = reference['reference']
        
        find = re.search("ver=.*",format(version))
        content = (urls, find.group())
        cont.append(content)
    return cont

cont = requestGet(bipTmb, bipAws)
for item in cont:
    treated_data = (item)
    print(treated_data)
```

output:

```
[('https://api1-foo', "ver=13.1.3.6'}"), ('https://api2-foo', "ver=13.1.3.6'}")]
```

Formated output expected:

```
https://api1-foo  ver=13.1.3.6,
https://api2-foo  ver=13.1.3.6
```

How can i transform this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reach the expected output looping through data.

```
for i in range(len(cont)):
    print(cont[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
print "\n".join(treated_data)
```